# perl cgi having trouble getting popup working

Tags: perl, cgi

What I am trying to accomplish when the user clicks the link it goes to a cgi page.  On the cgi page i need to do some checks then have a pop up send the user to a different page or do a redirect to a certain page. The redirect works but the popup doesn't.  It it possible to have a popup redirect that is in the else statement?

```
if($value)
{
    print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">  window.open(\"www.mysite.com/whatever/\",\"popup\", \"width=500\");</script>";
}
else
{
      print redirect(-url=>"www.site.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first solution that comes to mind is to use ajax. When your page loads, fire off a script that calls the method that does your checks. That method will return its info to the calling javascript method and you generate the popup or redirect as necessary.

You can't just send a string of javascript as a response to the browser and have it run. There has to be an event (the click) which triggers the script. The script must handle the return result.